# Designing an event-driven head-tracking library in C++

Tags: c++, api, architecture, opencv

I want to provide my team with a very simple C++ interface to OpenCV head tracking.

What architecture is best for this application?

Should I provide an "event-driven" API or should I make the client query this library whenever it wants a head position (yuck)?
Should I ask the client application to define callback functions? Can I do something similar to the [TUIO API in Processing][1], where you pass your class to a TUIO class and then the TUIO event dispatcher looks for your callback methods within that class (your class becomes a delegate)?   What's the C++ way to do this?

What about just asking for a function pointer to a static method with a given signature?

---

### Details

The specification would follow the lead of TUIO and Community Core Vision. Instead of blobs (fingertips on a touch-table) we're looking for heads with a Haar classifier.  Each new head gets a persistent ID. Then we just dispatch three events: `addHeadObject(id, x, y)`, `removeHeadObject(id)`, `updateHeadObject(id, x, y)`. Possibly with more parameters for communicating certainty, etc. The updateHeadObject event would happen at frame rate, up to 30 times per second.  The update rate cannot be improved by increasing some polling rate, so that is why the frame event coming from the camera device must ultimately drive the API.

Comment: It is hard to offer design advice on a specification that consists of "tracking heads".  I'm tempted to say "use tape" because it is just as arbitrary as any other answer.  What sort of events would you expect to be interesting, how frequently do they occur, are users of the library going to dominate system resources or is the library, etc.

Comment: The library can dominate system resources.

Comment: Insofar as the communicating certainty, would you ever be in a position where you weren't certain which head was which?  I can imagine a scenario where there was a pillar in the middle of a room which two people passed behind.  I suppose those would be delete/adds instead of updates?

Comment: It will be up to my implementation to solve that as well as possible, through Kalman filtering or whatever, but generally yes, these would break down to a remove and an add with a new ID. I will probably drop the certainty thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will follow the delegation pattern used in the TUIO C++ interface.   http://www.tuio.org/?cpp

```
MyHeadTrackerListener listener; // defines a listener
HeadTrackerClient client; // creates the client
client.addHeadTrackerListener(&listener); // registers the listener
client.connect(); // starts the client
```

As it says in the TUIO documentation:

> Your application needs to implement the TuioListener interface, and
>   has to be added to the TuioClient in order to receive messages.
>
> A TuioListener needs to implement the following methods:
>
> addTuioObject(TuioObject *tobj) this is called when an object becomes
>   visible removeTuioObject(TuioObject *tobj) an object was removed from
>   the table updateTuioObject(TuioObject *tobj) an object was moved on
>   the table surface addTuioCursor(TuioCursor *tcur) this is called when
>   a new cursor is detected removeTuioCursor(TuioCursor *tcur) a cursor
>   was removed from the table updateTuioCursor(TuioCursor *tcur) a cursor
>   was moving on the table surface refresh(TuioTime bundleTime) this
>   method is called after each bundle, use it to repaint your screen for
>   example

My client will be required to implement some head tracking event callback methods. It seems simple according to this outline, but I didn't know if it was normal to do it this way in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If the library is controlling the program flow, then callbacks are likely the easiest solution.  Abstracting it as a [coroutine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine) would also transition well into a multi-threaded solution if you wanted.  I offer this in terms of implementation and maintenance ease, not performance.

I have had success using `boost::signal` as the means to this end in the past, it is worth looking at.

Your public interface may be something equivalent, though perhaps a little more detailed.  I would expect pure virtual interfaces for most of these classes, but for demonstration plain structs are a little easier to read.

```
struct Head {
  int transient_id;
  int x, y;
};

struct Frame {
  std::vector<Head> heads;
};

struct HeadTracker {
  boost::signal<void(const Frame &)> updates;
};
```

I am not certain you absolutely need to fire an event when a head enters or leaves relevance.  The updates give `x` and `y`, so relevance changes are only the `transient_id`.  If a client didn't know which `transient_id` it had, it could just request the details.  Though it may be helpful to simplify processing.

I have some concerns about degrees of certainty with your identifiers, as they will theoretically (or maybe routinely) change.  It isn't clear to me if you are tracking identity of specific people (transient_id #35523 is Jane Doe) or just whether that shape is a head.

If Jane stepped out of the door, then back in, there would be two different people per the system.  This would simplify things and I would recommend modelling it this way behind the scenes anyway.

```
struct Head {
  int transient_id;
  int x, y;
  float is_head; // [0.0, 1.0]
};
```

Identifying this round shape in the scene as a head is one problem which is somewhat binary.  This should exist entirely independently of any belief in identity.  If you only saw the back of someone's head the belief that the head belonged to any one person would evolve as time went on.

You could have a statistic for every person on each frame.  That is a table of data, not a single value.  Though you would probably only want to act upon a finite number of them at any given time.

```
struct Person {
  int person_id;
  std::string name;
};

struct Head {
  int transient_id;
  int x, y;

  size_t getNumRanks();
  std::pair<Person, float> getPersonWithCertainty(size_t rank);
};

struct HeadTracker {
  boost::signal<void(const Frame &)> updates;
};
```

Putting the rankings in `Head` may be somewhat misleading (however convenient) depending on the system behavior.  If you had history of past frames then it is probably accurate.  If you only ever had one statistic at any given time, then it probably belongs in `HeadTracker`.

Computing the rankings seems like it would be pretty intense for a real-time system, but maybe it isn't.  I'm not certain that is what you are talking about, but it's certainly fun to think about. :)

Comment: Yes, the face _recognition_ problem is not something I want to bother with just yet. Most of my confusion relates to the observer pattern in C++, and whether it is really necessary for this small API. Because I think my client app will only ever need one delegate, so I'm not sure what benefits Boost::Signal would bring.  Am I correct to frame it as a choice between implementing an interface (subclassing a pure abstract class, in C++ world) vs. using some observer mechanism?

Comment: I have been overlooking flow control in this discussion. :( I would be creating the tracker object, and instructing it to start tracking, at which point the process would enter a blocking camera loop, walking through callbacks after each frame comes in.  TUIO uses pthreads, has a blocking and non-blocking client mode, and it provides lockObjects() and unlockObjects() method for the user application to set mutexes and prevent the event generating thread from updating while your user app is doing something with them. So I need to make sure I can spawn off a new thread and do all this...

Comment: @Matt M `boost::signals` are pretty easy, with `scoped_connection` it is hard to break an observer.  How you do the listening is easy to change though, don't worry about it too much.  You can always rewrite that in 20 minutes later.  What you communicate and when is a much riskier thing.  If that changes then the whole structure may have to, so I'd invest more thought in that.